# urlrewriting tuckey using Tuckey

Tags: spring, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

My project (we have Spring 3) needs to rewrite URLs from the form

```
localhost:8888/testing/test.htm?param1=val1&paramN=valN
```

to

```
localhost:8888/nottestinganymore/test.htm?param1=val1&paramN=valN
```

My current rule looks like:

```
<from>^/testing/(.*/)?([a-z0-9]*.htm.*)$</from>
<to type="passthrough">/nottestinganymore/$2</to>
```

But my query parameters are being doubled, so I am getting param1=val1,val1 and paramN=valN,valN...please help! This stuff is a huge pain.

To edit/add, we have use-query-string=true on the project and I doubt I can change that.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression needs some tweaking. Tuckey uses the java regular expression engine unless  specified otherwise. Hence the best way to deal with this is to write a small test case that will confirm if your regular expression is correct. For e.g. a slightly tweaked example of your regular expression with a test case is below.

```
@Test public void testRegularExpression()
{
    String regexp = "/testing/(.*)([a-z0-9]*.htm.*)$";
    String url = "localhost:8888/testing/test.htm?param1=val1&paramN=valN";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp);

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);

    if (matcher.find())
    {
        System.out.println("$1 : " + matcher.group(1) );
        System.out.println("$2 : " + matcher.group(2) );
    }
}
```

The above will print the output as follows :

$1 : test

$2 : .htm?param1=val1&paramN=valN

You can modify the expression now to see what "groups" you want to extract from URL and then form the target URL.